# Lambda expressions in PEG.js

Tags: javascript, lambda, peg, pegjs

I have [PEG grammar](http://jcubic.pl/modif.pegjs) problem with lambda expressions, they work if I use syntax:

```
x:{y:{x+y}}(20)(30)
```

which is equivalent of

```
(function(x) { return function(y) { return x+y; }; })(20)(30);
```

but this don't work

```
f:{f(10)}(x:{x*x})
```

which is equivalent of:

```
(function(f) { return f(10); })(function(x) { return x*x; })
```

Is it possible to make that second function work with PEG.js?

Comment: From the first lines on the file you linked, it appears the answer is no...

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error on the [online grammar parser](http://pegjs.majda.cz/online), I found that this works:

```
f:{f}(x:{x*x})(10)
```

Comment: It's because it create from left to right first create identity function then pass a function to that function and then execute that function. Is it possible to make it work from right to left like normal evaluation where it first execute arguments?

Comment: That seems to be a limitation of the grammar you're using, but I don't know the answer. Maybe if you modify the grammar or create your own. I never used PEGjs before, so I can't help you much further...